# Animated Page Transitions Working Incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, transition

So I've got a practice website in progress that currently has two pages linked to each other. I have it set up so that when the corresponding button on the Homepage is pressed, the History page slides in from the right. When the button leading to the Homepage is pressed, the History page slides back out to the right.

Unfortunately, when the History page is hidden again, nothing on the Homepage can be clicked, like there's an invisible div sitting on top. What's going on exactly, and how do I fix this?
Be prepared for a lot of code below this line.

Homepage HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Home">

        <div class="Box">
            <div id="PledisHover">
                <img class="Pledis" src="Pledis.png">
                    <img class="PledisHov" src="PledisHov.png">
        </div>

        <img class="SVT" src="SayTheName.png">

        <img class="Logo" src="Logo.png">

            <div id="HistHover" onClick="">
                <img src="HistButton.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='HistButtonHover5.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='HistButton.png'">
            </div>

            <div id="MembHover" onClick="">
                <img src="MemButton.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='MemButtonHov.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='MemButton.png'">
            </div>

            <div id="MedHover" onClick="">
                <img src="MedButton.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='MedButtonHov.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='MedButton.png'">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Hist">
        <img id="HomeButton" src="Home.png" onmouseover="this.src='HomeHov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Home.png'">
        <object id="Page" name="Page" type="text/html/css" data="SVTHist.html">
        </object>
    </div>

    <div id="Memb">
        <object id="Page" name="Page" type="text/html/css" data="SVTMemb.html"></object>
    </div>

    <div id="Med">
        <object id="Page" name="Page" type="text/html/css" data="SVTMed.html"></object>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Homepage CSS:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    #Wrapper {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
         }

    #Hist, #Memb, #Med {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 1364px;
        }

    #Home {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: linear-gradient(#F293BF 50%, #EBEFF8 50%);
        }

    .Box {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attatchment: fixed;
        background: linear-gradient(#94DBF7, #D2EAF7);
        height: 646px;
        width: 1202px;
        position: relative;
        left: 5.5%;
        top: 25px;
        }

        .Pledis, .PledisHov, .SVT, .Logo, #HistHover, #MembHover, #MedHover {
            position: absolute;
                    }

        #HistHover, #MembHover {
            top: 543px;
                   }

        #HistHover:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
                }

        .Pledis {
            top: 15%;
            left: 15%;
            }

            .PledisHov {
                top: 78px;
                left: 175px;
                transform: rotate(-15deg);
                   }

    .PledisHov, #PledisHover:hover .Pledis {
        display: none;
                    }

    .Pledis, #PledisHover:hover .PledisHov {
        display: block;
                    }

        .SVT {
            top: 10%;
            left: 20%;
            }

        .Logo {
            top:48%;
            left: 37%;
            }

    #HistHover {
        left: 25%;
           }

    #MembHover {
        left: 42%;
           }

    #MedHover {
        top: 553px;
        left: 59%;
          }

    #Page {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        }

        .animate {
            -webkit-animation-name: Slide;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            }

        @-webkit-keyframes Slide {
            from {transform: translateX(0px)}
            to {transform: translateX(-1364px)}
             }

        @keyframes Slide {
            from {transform: translateX(0px)}
            to {transform: translateX(-1364px)}
          }


        .animate2 {
            -webkit-animation-name: SlideOut;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
            }

        @-webkit-keyframes SlideOut {
            from {transform: translateX(0px)}
            to {transform: translateX(1364px)}
             }

        @keyframes SlideOut {
            from {transform: translateX(0px)}
            to {transform: translateX(1364px)}
          }

    #HomeButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        left: 9px;
          }
```

Homepage Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('HistHover').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('Hist').classList.add('animate');                                        });                                        

    document.getElementById('MembHover').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('Memb').classList.add('animate');
                                         });

    document.getElementById('MedHover').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Med').classList.add('animate');
                                         });

    document.getElementById('HomeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
            document.getElementById('Hist').classList.add('animate2');
                                         });
```

EDIT: @Jaromanda's response told me what I needed to know. I removed the Home button from the History page and instead inserted it into the div containing the History page object. The object no longer stays behind to make buttons unclickable. This problem has now been solved.
I updated the Home Page code to reflect my changes and removed the History Page code is it is no longer relevant.

Comment: at a guess, you're sliding the object containing the history page in, and you're sliding the content of the history page, rather than the object, out - thereby, keeping the object "on top" of your page, empty, but still on top

Comment: what do you do to hide the history page?

Comment: @MichaelCoker I have the history page loaded into an object, which is positioned directly to the right of the homepage. The homepage is contained with a wrapper with the "overflow: hidden" css styling. This prevents the history page from being seen when it's not supposed to be.

Comment: I see that, but once you click the image to show the history page, what do you click to hide the history page?

Comment: @MichaelCoker I click the home button (<div id="HomeButton">) on the history page.